# How to skip the matching the text in html attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex, string-matching

I want to get the index of matched string from the html to highlight the particular match in html.
The issue is I am using the tooltip with title in footnote link (which has footnote text). So.. when I am trying to highlight something in footnote it's highlighting in the footnote referenced tooltip.

Is there any way to skip the match of html attributes and jump to next match? (as I need the index of particular match so I can not use `$(selector).text();

please help me with this - below is the example of my code:

```
var selectedContent = $(selector).html();

var regex = new RegExp('/The text from footnote/', 'gi');

var indices = [];

while(result = regex.exec(selectedContent))
{
    indices .push(result.index);
}
```

The regex is matching the text in footnote tooltip which is used as footnote reference.

My code sample is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fxm5wzeb/). Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var regex = new RegExp("(?!<[^>]+)" + textToHighlight + "(?![^<]+>)", 'gi');

var finalHtml = selectedContent.replace(regex, '<highlight class="highlight">'+textToHighlight+'</highlight>');

if(finalHtml)
    $('#lipsumContainer').html(finalHtml);
```

[EDIT]

Here is a `highlightText()` function that searching for a string directly in textnodes, which means it won't affect attributes, however it won't find text if it's split between different elements.

In this example it will highlight selected text:

```js
function highlightText(node, text) {
  if (!node)
    return;

  if (node.nodeType == 3) { //process textnode
    const index = node.data.indexOf(text);

    if (index == -1)
      return;

    const textNodeMark = node.splitText(index),
          textNodeAfter = textNodeMark.splitText(text.length),
          mark = document.createElement("mark");

    mark.appendChild(textNodeMark);
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(mark, textNodeAfter);

  } else {
    for (let n of node.childNodes) {
      if (n.tagName !== "MARK")
        highlightText(n, text);
    }
  }
}

/* demo highlight selected text */

const container = document.getElementById("lipsumContainer");

container.addEventListener("click", e => {
  const text = document.getSelection().toString().trim();

  if (text === "")
    return;


  for(let m of container.querySelectorAll("mark"))
    m.parentNode.replaceChild(m.firstChild, m); // remove previous marks;

  container.normalize(); // join any split textnodes 
  highlightText(container, text); // add new highlighting
}, true);

$('#lipsum').on('mouseenter', '#_contentFoot1', function(){
    var tooltipPosition = $(this).position(); 
  var title = $(this).data('title');
    var tooltipHtml = '<div class="tooltip">'+
  '<span class="tooltiptext">'+title+'</span>'+'</div>'; 
    $('body').append(tooltipHtml);
    $('.tooltip').attr("style", "top: "+tooltipPosition.top+"px;left: "+tooltipPosition.left+"px;");  
})

$('#lipsum').on('mouseleave', '#_contentFoot1', function(){
    $('.tooltip').remove();
})
```

```css
.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  /* At the bottom of the tooltip */
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

mark {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="lipsumContainer">
  <div id="lipsum">
<p><b>bold</b> <i>italic</i></p>
<p><b>bold</b> <i>italic</i></p>
    <p>
      Vivamus vel commodo nisl, sed maximus lectus. Donec semper suscipit porta. Ut facilisis turpis pellentesque purus laoreet sagittis. Donec at scelerisque dui. Nullam hendrerit eros et lacinia venenatis. Nullam sodales nulla sit amet est ultrices,
      sit amet tempus risus consequat.<a id="_contentFoot1" href="#_foot1" data-toglggle="tooltip" data-title="The 1st footnote text"><sup>[1]</sup></a> Fusce suscipit ipsum vel dapibus sagittis. Nullam tellus nisl, egestas ut feugiat non, porttitor
      eget erat. Suspendisse placerat dictum nulla non sollicitudin. Maecenas nec tortor felis. Donec id cursus ligula, a volutpat sapien.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="footnotes">
    <p id="_foot1">
      <a href="#_contentFoot1">[1]</a> <span>The 1st footnote text</span>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.. It worked but I have one question related to it according to current scenario.. I used (?<!<[^>]+) + textToHighlight.
As you can see I am using Negative Lookbehind in my regex. Will it affect the performance of the page as the site has big pages and the page can have multiple highlights submitted by user.

Comment: I've updated the answer with another method

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7m6cna9r/3/ - here is the example.. I thought about the scenario overnight and I got remembered what was the exact problem I was facing with the regex given by you.. by reason of I used the negative lookbehind

Comment: Yeah, basically there are 2 issues, first is the regex, which only capture complete text between `>` and searched string and second if there are more then 1 found strings, after first one highlighted the index of the second one is changed and is not accounted for. So it's better simply use `replace()` instead of capturing indexes. I've updated the answer with `replace` method

Answer (score 0):

In the example, I have create a variable countMatch to skip the first match.

```
 

https://jsfiddle.net/f1sbh7x6/
```